# Cookie code not working across sub domains

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, phpbb3

I recently just changed my domain name, and on the previous domain I coded a tracking cookies that helped me determine where my customers where coming from by recording the referring domain...

Ever since I changed the domain, no matter what I do, I can't get it to work again...

on the front end is a wordpress site and I run the following...

```
function set_cookie_data()
{
    //visitor url tracking cookie
    if(isset($_GET['ref'])) 
        {
            setcookie('ref', $_GET['ref'], ((60 * 60 * 24 * 60) + time()), '/', 'theforexguy.com'); 

        }

elseif(!isset($_COOKIE['ref']))
        {
            $referinghtml = htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags(stripslashes(stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))));
            $referinghtml = parse_url($referinghtml, PHP_URL_HOST);
            setcookie('ref', $referinghtml, ((60 * 60 * 24 * 60) + time()), '/', 'theforexguy.com');
        }



} 
add_action('init', 'set_cookie_data');
```

On my subdomain, where I run my membership area around a phpbb3 forum system. When a user signs up it's meant to be able to access that cookie data and store it in the database with the rest of the user data...

```
'referer' => (isset($_COOKIE['ref'])) ? $_COOKIE['ref'] : 0
```

The result in the database seems to only be 0 now.

I used to call the cookie $_COOKIE['referer'], but I changed it to $_COOKIE['ref'] just in case the cookie from the old domain was conflicting some how.

I also tried putting the leading dot on the domain parameter when setting the cookie, it didn't make any different.

Can anyone spot a problem here, it's really frustrating me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your cookiedomain to

```
.theforexguy.com
```

The subdomain is running under the same domainname?

Comment: I did try it with the leading dot, I will add it back there. Yes the domain name is the same for the subdomain. The thing is, this was working before I changed my domain name.